# Как инициализировать static final переменную в try catch

Tags: java

Добрый день. Мне надо инициализировать static final переменную, делаю я это в статическом блоке инициализации. Фишка в том, что сама инициализация переменной может выкинуть исключительную ситуацию, я инициализацию обернул в try{} catch, но тут мне компилятор говорит, что переменная может быть не инициализирована, оно и правильно, но как мне тогда инициализировать эту переменную?! Вот как пример код:

```
public class Example {
  public static final Connection connection;

  static {
    try {
      connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + PATH); //Вот эта строка может выкинуть исключительную ситуацию
    } catch (Exception ignored) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: `connection = null;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Example {
    public static final Connection connection;

    static {
        Connection c = null;
        try {
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + PATH);
        }
        catch (Exception exc) {}
        finally {
            connection = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое